# docker ADD with symlinks

Tags: docker, ubuntu, symlink, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

When I do `sudo docker build -t test -f 7.1/Dockerfile .` docker fails on step 8/10:

```
Step 8/10 : ADD etc/php /usr/local/etc/php
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat etc/php: file does not exist
```

I don't understand. `etc/php` is symlinked to another directory. Shouldn't that work?

If I do `ls -latr etc/php` I get this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scbn scbn 43 Sep 11 17:48 etc/php -> /home/neubert/devops/containers/common/etc/php
```

If I do `cd etc/php && ls -latr` I get this:

```
total 84
drwxr-xr-x 2 scbn scbn  4096 Jan  3  2021 conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 5 scbn scbn  4096 Jan  3  2021 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 scbn scbn 70125 Jan 26  2021 php.ini
drwxr-xr-x 3 scbn scbn  4096 Jan 26  2021 .
```

Comment: `Shouldn't that work?` No, because docker can only access the build context, nothing from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

> $ docker build --help
>
> Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Here, `PATH | URL | -` is so called build context, you usually use `.`, but it could be other path. When docker build, it will tar all the contents in `build context`, then pass it to docker engine. So, the `COPY` in Dockerfile could just reference the item in `build context`.

For your scenario:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 scbn scbn 43 Sep 11 17:48 etc/php -> /home/neubert/devops/containers/common/etc/php

Above I guess the symbol link `etc/php` is in your build context, while the real folder `/home/neubert/devops/containers/common/etc/php` not, so build fail, you have to in some way assure the real targe also in `build context`.